# A-Frame 360 image for sky

Tags: cors, aframe

I am trying to use a URL for a 360 photo shot with a Theta S as my sky. I have been able to do this with local files, but when I try to reference it as a URL it doesn't work. The code seems simple, so I am not sure why it is not working. I have tried running it on multiple browsers, including Nightly.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a-scene>
            <a-assets>
                <img id="mall" src="http://www.mycode.zone/res/dc-mall.JPG">
            </a-assets>
            <a-sky src="#mall"></a-sky>
            <a-entity position="0 0 1.5">
                <a-camera></a-camera>
            </a-entity>
    </a-scene>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is hosted in such a way that it does not allow other sites to use the image in the doc because of the server's CORS policy. If I use this example sky box image from Mozilla your code works:

```
<img id="mall" src="https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/showcase/composite/lake.jpg">
```

Look in your developer console with your original code you'll see something like this:

> Access to Image at 'http://www.mycode.zone/res/dc-mall.JPG' from
>   origin 'http://s.codepen.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://s.codepen.io' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Here's the working codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dOdmNo